# offset or move x & y coordinate of a line to the white pixel lines in binary image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, offset

I have the x & y coordinate of the red line. And I want to move the red line towards the upper broken white lines in the binary image. So that I can connect the broken lines using the red line coordinate. since the image is a binary image I got the upper broken white line coordinate using the code written below. But I was stuck and don't know what to do to move the red lines towards the white broken line.
[image]

After moving the red line towards the white split line it looks like this. I draw it manually for illustration. Note that, some of the white split lines are overlapped and I want to move the coordinate to the closet coordinate of the white line, not the overlapped one. I appreciate any suggestions with a set of functions. Thank you.

[image]

```
x_axis = [257.0, 258.0, 259.0, 260.0, 261.0, 261.0, 263.0, 264.0, 265.0, 265.0, 267.0, 268.0, 269.0, 269.0, 270.0, 271.0, 272.0, 273.0, 273.0, 274.0, 275.0, 276.0, 277.0, 277.0, 279.0, 280.0, 281.0, 281.0, 282.0, 284.0, 285.0, 285.0, 286.0, 287.0, 288.0, 289.0, 289.0, 290.0, 291.0, 292.0, 293.0, 295.0, 297.0, 297.0, 299.0, 300.0, 301.0, 301.0, 302.0, 304.0, 306.0, 307.0, 308.0, 309.0, 310.0, 311.0, 312.0, 313.0, 313.0, 315.0, 316.0, 317.0, 317.0, 319.0, 320.0, 321.0, 322.0, 323.0, 324.0, 325.0, 325.0, 326.0, 327.0, 328.0, 329.0, 330.0, 331.0, 332.0, 333.0, 333.0, 335.0, 336.0, 337.0, 337.0, 339.0, 340.0, 342.0, 344.0, 346.0, 347.0, 348.0, 349.0, 349.0, 350.0, 351.0, 352.0, 353.0, 355.0, 357.0, 359.0, 360.0, 361.0, 362.0, 363.0, 364.0, 365.0, 366.0, 367.0, 368.0, 369.0, 369.0, 370.0, 371.0, 372.0, 373.0, 374.0, 375.0, 376.0, 377.0, 378.0, 379.0, 380.0, 381.0, 383.0, 384.0, 385.0, 386.0, 387.0, 388.0, 389.0, 390.0, 391.0, 392.0, 394.0, 396.0, 398.0, 399.0, 400.0, 401.0, 402.0, 403.0, 404.0, 405.0, 407.0, 409.0, 411.0, 412.0, 413.0, 414.0, 415.0, 416.0, 417.0, 418.0, 419.0, 420.0, 422.0, 423.0, 424.0, 425.0, 426.0, 427.0, 428.0, 429.0, 430.0, 432.0, 434.0, 435.0, 436.0, 437.0, 438.0, 439.0, 440.0, 445.0, 447.0, 453.0, 455.0, 456.0, 457.0, 458.0, 459.0, 460.0, 461.0, 462.0, 463.0, 464.0, 465.0, 466.0, 468.0, 469.0, 469.0, 472.0, 474.0, 473.0, 473.0, 475.0, 479.0, 481.0, 485.0, 487.0, 488.0, 489.0, 490.0, 491.0, 492.0, 493.0, 494.0, 495.0, 496.0, 498.0, 499.0, 500.0, 505.0, 506.0, 507.0, 508.0, 509.0, 510.0, 511.0, 512.0, 513.0, 515.0, 517.0, 519.0, 524.0, 525.0, 526.0, 527.0, 528.0, 529.0, 530.0, 532.0, 534.0, 536.0, 537.0, 538.0, 539.0, 540.0, 545.0, 547.0, 553.0, 555.0, 556.0, 557.0, 558.0, 559.0, 560.0, 561.0, 562.0, 563.0, 564.0, 565.0, 570.0, 572.0, 577.0, 578.0, 579.0, 580.0, 585.0, 586.0, 587.0, 588.0, 597.0, 599.0, 600.0, 601.0, 606.0, 607.0, 608.0, 609.0, 610.0, 612.0, 622.0, 624.0, 629.0, 630.0, 631.0, 632.0, 637.0, 638.0, 639.0, 640.0, 641.0, 642.0, 646.0, 647.0, 648.0, 649.0, 650.0, 651.0, 652.0, 653.0, 666.0, 668.0, 669.0, 670.0, 671.0, 672.0, 677.0, 678.0, 679.0, 680.0, 681.0, 682.0, 695.0, 697.0, 702.0, 703.0, 704.0, 705.0, 722.0, 724.0, 725.0, 726.0, 727.0, 728.0, 729.0, 730.0, 739.0, 741.0, 751.0, 753.0, 766.0, 767.0, 768.0, 769.0, 771.0, 772.0, 774.0, 775.0, 778.0, 779.0, 783.0, 784.0, 785.0, 786.0, 795.0, 796.0, 797.0, 798.0, 805.0, 807.0, 808.0, 809.0, 810.0, 819.0, 821.0, 824.0, 825.0, 826.0, 827.0, 833.0, 834.0, 852.0, 854.0, 858.0, 860.0, 862.0, 887.0, 888.0, 889.0, 890.0, 891.0, 892.0, 908.0, 909.0, 910.0, 911.0, 924.0, 926.0, 943.0, 944.0, 945.0, 947.0, 948.0, 950.0, 952.0, 985.0, 987.0, 1012.0, 1013.0, 1014.0, 1015.0, 1016.0, 1017.0, 1045.0, 1047.0, 1052.0, 1054.0, 1057.0, 1058.0, 1059.0, 1060.0, 1077.0, 1078.0, 1114.0, 1116.0, 1145.0, 1146.0, 1147.0, 1148.0, 1149.0, 1150.0, 1183.0, 1185.0, 1206.0, 1207.0, 1231.0, 1232.0, 1233.0, 1234.0, 1273.0, 1274.0, 1296.0, 1298.0, 1340.0, 1341.0, 1413.0, 1414.0, 1479.0, 1480.0, 1482.0, 1483.0, 1484.0, 1485.0, 1486.0, 1487.0, 1494.0, 1495.0, 1534.0, 1535.0, 1536.0, 1537.0, 1561.0, 1562.0, 1618.0, 1620.0, 1642.0, 1643.0, 1682.0, 1684.0, 1716.0, 1717.0, 1721.0, 1722.0, 1723.0, 1724.0, 1725.0, 1726.0, 1727.0, 1728.0, 1754.0, 1755.0, 1756.0, 1757.0, 1808.0, 1809.0, 1881.0, 1882.0, 1895.0, 1897.0, 1948.0, 1949.0, 2022.0, 2023.0, 2054.0, 2056.0, 2060.0, 2062.0, 2074.0, 2075.0, 2076.0, 2077.0, 2091.0, 2093.0, 2110.0, 2111.0, 2118.0, 2120.0, 2138.0, 2139.0, 2140.0, 2141.0, 2184.0, 2186.0, 2200.0, 2201.0, 2202.0, 2203.0, 2213.0, 2214.0, 2219.0, 2221.0, 2244.0, 2246.0, 2277.0, 2279.0, 2297.0, 2298.0, 2299.0, 2300.0, 2306.0, 2307.0, 2308.0, 2309.0, 2310.0, 2311.0, 2312.0, 2319.0, 2320.0, 2328.0, 2329.0, 2330.0, 2331.0, 2345.0, 2347.0, 2361.0, 2363.0, 2373.0, 2374.0, 2375.0, 2376.0, 2390.0, 2392.0, 2402.0, 2404.0, 2410.0, 2411.0, 2412.0, 2413.0, 2427.0, 2429.0, 2435.0, 2437.0, 2447.0, 2448.0, 2449.0, 2450.0, 2455.0, 2456.0, 2457.0, 2458.0, 2463.0, 2464.0, 2465.0, 2466.0, 2473.0, 2474.0, 2478.0, 2479.0, 2480.0, 2481.0, 2486.0, 2487.0, 2488.0, 2489.0, 2490.0, 2491.0, 2492.0, 2493.0, 2494.0, 2495.0, 2496.0, 2497.0, 2498.0, 2499.0, 2501.0, 2502.0, 2506.0, 2507.0, 2508.0, 2509.0, 2510.0, 2511.0, 2512.0, 2514.0, 2515.0, 2516.0, 2517.0, 2518.0, 2519.0, 2520.0, 2521.0, 2527.0, 2529.0, 2535.0, 2536.0, 2537.0, 2538.0, 2539.0, 2540.0, 2541.0, 2542.0, 2551.0, 2552.0, 2553.0, 2554.0, 2555.0, 2556.0, 2557.0, 2558.0, 2563.0, 2564.0, 2565.0, 2566.0, 2571.0, 2572.0, 2573.0, 2574.0, 2575.0, 2576.0, 2577.0, 2578.0, 2583.0, 2584.0, 2585.0, 2586.0, 2592.0, 2594.0, 2600.0, 2601.0, 2602.0, 2603.0, 2604.0, 2606.0, 2612.0, 2613.0, 2614.0, 2615.0, 2624.0, 2625.0, 2626.0, 2627.0, 2632.0, 2633.0, 2634.0, 2635.0, 2636.0, 2637.0, 2638.0, 2639.0, 2640.0, 2641.0, 2642.0, 2643.0, 2649.0, 2651.0, 2657.0, 2659.0, 2665.0, 2667.0, 2673.0, 2674.0, 2675.0, 2676.0, 2677.0, 2678.0, 2679.0, 2680.0, 2685.0, 2686.0, 2687.0, 2688.0, 2693.0, 2694.0, 2695.0, 2696.0, 2697.0, 2698.0, 2699.0, 2700.0, 2701.0, 2702.0, 2703.0, 2704.0, 2705.0, 2706.0, 2707.0, 2708.0, 2713.0, 2714.0, 2715.0, 2716.0, 2717.0, 2718.0, 2719.0, 2720.0, 2725.0, 2726.0, 2727.0, 2728.0, 2729.0, 2730.0, 2731.0, 2732.0, 2737.0, 2738.0, 2739.0, 2740.0, 2741.0, 2742.0, 2743.0, 2744.0, 2749.0, 2750.0, 2752.0, 2754.0, 2756.0, 2757.0, 2762.0, 2763.0, 2764.0, 2765.0, 2765.0, 2766.0, 2768.0, 2770.0, 2776.0, 2777.0, 2778.0, 2779.0, 2780.0, 2781.0, 2782.0, 2783.0, 2784.0, 2785.0, 2785.0, 2786.0, 2788.0, 2790.0, 2792.0, 2794.0, 2796.0, 2798.0, 2800.0, 2802.0, 2804.0, 2806.0, 2808.0, 2810.0, 2812.0, 2814.0, 2816.0, 2818.0, 2820.0, 2822.0, 2824.0, 2826.0, 2827.0, 2828.0, 2829.0, 2830.0, 2831.0, 2832.0, 2833.0, 2834.0, 2836.0, 2838.0, 2840.0, 2842.0, 2843.0, 2844.0, 2845.0, 2846.0, 2847.0, 2848.0, 2849.0, 2850.0, 2851.0, 2852.0, 2853.0, 2854.0, 2855.0, 2856.0, 2857.0, 2858.0, 2859.0, 2860.0, 2861.0, 2863.0, 2863.0, 2864.0, 2869.0, 2870.0, 2871.0, 2872.0, 2873.0, 2875.0, 2875.0, 2876.0, 2877.0, 2879.0, 2879.0, 2880.0, 2881.0, 2883.0, 2883.0, 2885.0, 2886.0, 2887.0, 2888.0, 2889.0, 2891.0, 2891.0, 2893.0, 2895.0, 2895.0, 2897.0, 2898.0, 2899.0, 2900.0, 2901.0, 2902.0, 2903.0, 2904.0, 2905.0, 2906.0, 2908.0, 2908.0, 2909.0, 2910.0, 2912.0, 2912.0, 2913.0, 2914.0, 2916.0, 2916.0, 2917.0, 2918.0, 2920.0, 2920.0, 2922.0, 2924.0, 2924.0, 2926.0, 2928.0, 2928.0]

y_axis = [579.0, 578.0, 578.0, 577.0, 577.0, 573.0, 571.0, 571.0, 570.0, 569.0, 567.0, 567.0, 566.0, 562.0, 561.0, 561.0, 560.0, 560.0, 558.0, 557.0, 557.0, 556.0, 556.0, 554.0, 552.0, 552.0, 551.0, 549.0, 548.0, 548.0, 547.0, 545.0, 544.0, 544.0, 543.0, 543.0, 541.0, 540.0, 540.0, 539.0, 539.0, 537.0, 537.0, 535.0, 533.0, 533.0, 532.0, 530.0, 529.0, 529.0, 527.0, 527.0, 526.0, 526.0, 525.0, 525.0, 524.0, 524.0, 522.0, 520.0, 520.0, 519.0, 518.0, 516.0, 516.0, 515.0, 515.0, 514.0, 514.0, 513.0, 511.0, 510.0, 510.0, 509.0, 509.0, 508.0, 508.0, 507.0, 507.0, 505.0, 503.0, 503.0, 502.0, 501.0, 499.0, 499.0, 497.0, 497.0, 495.0, 495.0, 494.0, 494.0, 492.0, 491.0, 491.0, 490.0, 490.0, 488.0, 488.0, 486.0, 486.0, 485.0, 485.0, 484.0, 484.0, 483.0, 483.0, 482.0, 482.0, 481.0, 479.0, 478.0, 478.0, 477.0, 477.0, 476.0, 476.0, 475.0, 475.0, 474.0, 474.0, 473.0, 473.0, 471.0, 471.0, 470.0, 470.0, 469.0, 469.0, 468.0, 468.0, 467.0, 467.0, 465.0, 465.0, 463.0, 463.0, 462.0, 462.0, 461.0, 461.0, 460.0, 460.0, 458.0, 458.0, 456.0, 456.0, 455.0, 455.0, 454.0, 454.0, 453.0, 453.0, 452.0, 452.0, 450.0, 450.0, 449.0, 449.0, 448.0, 448.0, 447.0, 447.0, 448.0, 448.0, 450.0, 450.0, 449.0, 449.0, 448.0, 448.0, 447.0, 447.0, 445.0, 445.0, 443.0, 443.0, 442.0, 442.0, 441.0, 441.0, 440.0, 440.0, 439.0, 439.0, 438.0, 438.0, 436.0, 436.0, 435.0, 432.0, 432.0, 431.0, 430.0, 428.0, 428.0, 430.0, 430.0, 428.0, 428.0, 427.0, 427.0, 426.0, 426.0, 425.0, 425.0, 424.0, 424.0, 422.0, 422.0, 421.0, 421.0, 420.0, 420.0, 419.0, 419.0, 418.0, 418.0, 417.0, 417.0, 415.0, 415.0, 413.0, 413.0, 412.0, 412.0, 411.0, 411.0, 410.0, 410.0, 408.0, 408.0, 406.0, 406.0, 405.0, 405.0, 404.0, 404.0, 402.0, 402.0, 400.0, 400.0, 399.0, 399.0, 398.0, 398.0, 397.0, 397.0, 396.0, 396.0, 395.0, 395.0, 393.0, 393.0, 392.0, 392.0, 391.0, 391.0, 390.0, 390.0, 389.0, 389.0, 387.0, 387.0, 386.0, 386.0, 385.0, 385.0, 384.0, 384.0, 382.0, 382.0, 380.0, 380.0, 379.0, 379.0, 378.0, 378.0, 377.0, 377.0, 376.0, 376.0, 375.0, 375.0, 374.0, 374.0, 373.0, 373.0, 372.0, 372.0, 371.0, 371.0, 369.0, 369.0, 368.0, 368.0, 367.0, 367.0, 366.0, 366.0, 365.0, 365.0, 364.0, 364.0, 362.0, 362.0, 361.0, 361.0, 360.0, 360.0, 358.0, 358.0, 357.0, 357.0, 356.0, 356.0, 355.0, 355.0, 353.0, 353.0, 351.0, 351.0, 350.0, 350.0, 349.0, 349.0, 348.0, 348.0, 349.0, 349.0, 348.0, 348.0, 347.0, 347.0, 346.0, 346.0, 345.0, 345.0, 344.0, 344.0, 346.0, 345.0, 345.0, 344.0, 344.0, 342.0, 342.0, 341.0, 341.0, 342.0, 342.0, 341.0, 341.0, 339.0, 339.0, 341.0, 339.0, 339.0, 338.0, 338.0, 337.0, 337.0, 336.0, 336.0, 335.0, 335.0, 334.0, 334.0, 332.0, 332.0, 331.0, 332.0, 332.0, 333.0, 333.0, 331.0, 331.0, 329.0, 329.0, 328.0, 328.0, 327.0, 327.0, 326.0, 326.0, 324.0, 324.0, 326.0, 326.0, 325.0, 325.0, 324.0, 324.0, 323.0, 323.0, 321.0, 321.0, 320.0, 320.0, 319.0, 319.0, 318.0, 318.0, 316.0, 316.0, 315.0, 315.0, 314.0, 314.0, 313.0, 313.0, 312.0, 312.0, 310.0, 310.0, 309.0, 309.0, 308.0, 308.0, 307.0, 307.0, 308.0, 308.0, 309.0, 309.0, 310.0, 310.0, 309.0, 309.0, 308.0, 308.0, 307.0, 307.0, 306.0, 306.0, 308.0, 308.0, 307.0, 307.0, 309.0, 309.0, 308.0, 308.0, 309.0, 309.0, 310.0, 310.0, 311.0, 311.0, 310.0, 310.0, 311.0, 311.0, 312.0, 312.0, 311.0, 311.0, 310.0, 310.0, 308.0, 308.0, 307.0, 307.0, 306.0, 306.0, 308.0, 308.0, 306.0, 306.0, 307.0, 307.0, 308.0, 308.0, 310.0, 310.0, 309.0, 309.0, 311.0, 311.0, 312.0, 312.0, 313.0, 313.0, 315.0, 315.0, 316.0, 316.0, 317.0, 317.0, 316.0, 316.0, 318.0, 318.0, 320.0, 320.0, 322.0, 322.0, 323.0, 323.0, 324.0, 324.0, 323.0, 324.0, 324.0, 325.0, 325.0, 326.0, 326.0, 325.0, 325.0, 326.0, 326.0, 327.0, 327.0, 329.0, 329.0, 331.0, 331.0, 332.0, 332.0, 333.0, 333.0, 335.0, 335.0, 337.0, 337.0, 338.0, 338.0, 339.0, 339.0, 341.0, 341.0, 343.0, 343.0, 344.0, 344.0, 345.0, 345.0, 346.0, 346.0, 347.0, 347.0, 348.0, 348.0, 349.0, 349.0, 348.0, 348.0, 349.0, 349.0, 350.0, 350.0, 351.0, 351.0, 352.0, 352.0, 353.0, 353.0, 354.0, 354.0, 355.0, 355.0, 356.0, 356.0, 357.0, 357.0, 356.0, 356.0, 357.0, 357.0, 358.0, 358.0, 359.0, 358.0, 358.0, 359.0, 359.0, 360.0, 360.0, 361.0, 361.0, 360.0, 360.0, 362.0, 362.0, 363.0, 363.0, 364.0, 364.0, 365.0, 365.0, 366.0, 366.0, 367.0, 367.0, 368.0, 368.0, 369.0, 369.0, 370.0, 370.0, 371.0, 371.0, 372.0, 372.0, 373.0, 373.0, 374.0, 374.0, 375.0, 375.0, 376.0, 376.0, 377.0, 377.0, 378.0, 378.0, 380.0, 380.0, 381.0, 381.0, 382.0, 382.0, 384.0, 384.0, 385.0, 385.0, 386.0, 386.0, 387.0, 387.0, 388.0, 388.0, 389.0, 389.0, 390.0, 390.0, 391.0, 391.0, 392.0, 392.0, 393.0, 393.0, 394.0, 394.0, 396.0, 396.0, 398.0, 398.0, 400.0, 400.0, 401.0, 401.0, 402.0, 402.0, 403.0, 403.0, 404.0, 404.0, 405.0, 405.0, 406.0, 406.0, 407.0, 407.0, 408.0, 408.0, 409.0, 409.0, 410.0, 410.0, 411.0, 411.0, 412.0, 412.0, 413.0, 413.0, 414.0, 414.0, 415.0, 415.0, 416.0, 416.0, 417.0, 417.0, 418.0, 418.0, 419.0, 419.0, 420.0, 420.0, 421.0, 421.0, 422.0, 422.0, 423.0, 423.0, 424.0, 424.0, 425.0, 425.0, 426.0, 426.0, 427.0, 427.0, 429.0, 429.0, 430.0, 430.0, 431.0, 431.0, 432.0, 434.0, 435.0, 435.0, 437.0, 437.0, 438.0, 438.0, 439.0, 439.0, 440.0, 440.0, 441.0, 441.0, 442.0, 444.0, 445.0, 445.0, 447.0, 447.0, 449.0, 449.0, 451.0, 451.0, 453.0, 453.0, 455.0, 455.0, 457.0, 457.0, 459.0, 459.0, 461.0, 461.0, 463.0, 463.0, 465.0, 465.0, 466.0, 466.0, 467.0, 467.0, 468.0, 468.0, 469.0, 469.0, 471.0, 471.0, 473.0, 473.0, 474.0, 474.0, 475.0, 475.0, 476.0, 476.0, 477.0, 477.0, 478.0, 478.0, 479.0, 479.0, 480.0, 480.0, 481.0, 481.0, 482.0, 482.0, 484.0, 487.0, 488.0, 488.0, 489.0, 489.0, 490.0, 490.0, 492.0, 493.0, 494.0, 494.0, 496.0, 497.0, 498.0, 498.0, 500.0, 502.0, 502.0, 503.0, 503.0, 504.0, 504.0, 506.0, 508.0, 508.0, 510.0, 511.0, 513.0, 513.0, 514.0, 514.0, 515.0, 515.0, 516.0, 516.0, 517.0, 517.0, 519.0, 520.0, 521.0, 521.0, 523.0, 524.0, 525.0, 525.0, 527.0, 528.0, 529.0, 529.0, 531.0, 533.0, 533.0, 535.0, 537.0, 537.0, 539.0, 541.0]

image= cv2.imread("image.png")  # binary image
indices = np.where(image!= [0])
coordinates = (indices[0], indices[1]) # y & x coordinate of the white pixels (lines) in the binary image
```

Comment: Why don't you make an attempt to connect the disjoint lines?

Comment: You will to change x_axis and y_axis all by urself.

Comment: @JeruLuke Thank you for your swift response. However, I have attempted multiple times but i didn't get a good result. Since I am working on a bunch of images connecting automatically doesn't work for all images. As such, I have decided to use the coordinate of the red line so that I can offset it or move it to the white pixel. Which I am trying to get some help. I would appreciate any suggestions?

Comment: @toyotaSupra I am aware that I have to change axises but I was confused in what distance to change the axises to be able to move it the the nearset splitted white line or coordinate. Since some of the spliited white lines have overlapped lines. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You could measure the vertical distance between each white point and the red point (vertically below it). Then get the average distance and move every red point up by that much.

Comment: @fmw42, Thank you for your response. Since the length of the data for white data points and red points are different how can I calculate the distance between each white data point and red data point?

Comment: For each white point, get its X coordinate. Then find the red point with the same X coordinate. Then for those two points, find the Y distance between them.

Answer (score 1):

In recipe form:

1. Define an initial state for the configuration of the red curve.
2. Define a cost function that expresses "how ugly" a certain configuration of the red line is given the white dots. It should be minimal when the configuration is "ideal", i.e. "least ugly". For example: the sum of the squared distances along the vertical direction of the white points from the red curve.
3. Define an allowed class of transformations of the red line, parametrized on some numbers. For example, a  rigid vertical shift, parametrized by the length of the shift.
4. Optimize: search the space of the transformation parameter(s) that minimize the cost of the configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your kind suggestions. I would appreciate it if you could provide the general steps code to implement the recipe you described? Thank you